# MySQL JSON: finding value of sibling element in sub-array

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

I have the following (pseudo)JSON in a type JSON (LONGTEXT) column in my MariaDB 10.2

```
{"order":
    {"otherstuff":...},
    {"dates":
        [
            {
            "typeId":2,
            "date":"2019-05-21 09:00:00"
            },
            {
            "typeId":4,
            "date":"2019-05-21 10:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I need is the order's date while I know which type I need (4).
An order can have a number of dates identified by their typeId. typeId 4 is not always in second position.

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(`json`, 'one', 4, NULL, '$.dates[*].typeId'))
// gives me: $.dates[1].typeId
```

My first thought now was to `REPLACE` typeId with date, but that complains about mixed collations.
How would I (more elegantly) reference the 'date' value here?

Also, the query is supposed to be the expression of a `GENERATED` column in my table. Since date id4 is not necessarily there for every order, I tried this:

```
SELECT IF(4 IN (JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.dates[*].typeId')), 'yes', 'no')
// above condition evaluates to [2, 4]
```

I have trimmed away '[' and ']' but then it only gives me a 'yes' if 4 is first in the array (is it an array?).
So (without brackets):

`[4, 7]` -> yes

`[2, 4]` -> no

I'm assuming this doesn't get recognized as an array of values but a string. Then why does it give me 'yes' if my needle is in first position?

Instead of yes and no I obviously want to use the date and NULL.

The MySQL JSON functions are quite new to me. So maybe someone could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

**Option 1**:

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_UNQUOTE(
    JSON_EXTRACT(
      `json`,
      REPLACE(
        JSON_UNQUOTE(
          JSON_SEARCH(
            `json`,
            'one',
            4,
            NULL,
            '$.order.dates[*].typeId'
          )
        ),
        'typeId',
        'date'
      )
    )
  ) `date`;
```

**Option 2**:

```sql
SELECT
  IF(
    JSON_CONTAINS(
      JSON_EXTRACT(
        `json`,
        '$.order.dates[*].typeId'
      ),
      4
    ),
    'yes',
    'no'
  ) `exists`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8790ff0ac69a0c22b18e92b590da2a9b).

Comment: Thank you. I was on the same path and will check out the first option tomorrow. The REPLACE threw a mixed collation error/warning. I was surprised by that since everything runs on utf-8 - should be fine. But I will follow up on this further.
The second option "JSON_CONTAINS" looks promising. I guess I was looking for something like that.
As I said, will be back on it tomorrow and try it out. Thanks for now. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works on MySQL 8.

It assumes a table `my_table` with a column `jsonData` which looks like this:

```json
{
    "dates": [
        {
            "type": "created",
            "dt": "2021-10-10"
        },
        {
            "type": "updated",
            "dt": "2021-10-11"
        },
    ]
}
```

TL;DR SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT(
        JSON_EXTRACT(
            jsondata,
            '$.dates[*].dt'
        ),
        JSON_UNQUOTE(
            JSON_SEARCH(
                JSON_EXTRACT(
                        jsonData,
                        '$.dates[*].type'
                    ),
                'one',
                'updated' -- the date field to load
            )
        )
  ) as dateUpdated
from my_table
```

Here's the worked solution for it.

```sql
SELECT
    
    -- The first step is to extract all the date types as an array 
    JSON_EXTRACT(
            jsonData,
            '$.dates[*].type'
    ) as jsonDateTypesAsArray,
    
    -- We can get a companion array of values, where the position within the array is the same as the types array above
    JSON_EXTRACT(
            jsonData,
            '$.dates[*].dt'
        ) as jsonDateValuesAsArray,
        
    -- Next, we search the types array for the first date type     
    JSON_UNQUOTE(
        JSON_SEARCH(                        
            JSON_EXTRACT(                   -- This is jsonDateTypesAsArray above
                    jsonData,
                    '$.dates[*].type'
                ),
            'one',
            'updated'                       -- This is the date field to load
            )
        ) as jsonLocalPathOfMatchingDate,

    -- Now we can call JSON_EXTRACT on the payload to get the path in jsonLocalPathOfMatchingDate
    JSON_UNQUOTE(
      JSON_EXTRACT(
        JSON_EXTRACT(                     -- This is jsonDateValuesAsArray above
            jsonData,
            '$.dates[*].dt'
        ),
        JSON_UNQUOTE(                     -- This is jsonLocalPathOfMatchingDate above 
            JSON_SEARCH(
                JSON_EXTRACT(
                        jsonData,
                        '$.dates[*].type'
                    ),
                'one',
                'updated.'                -- Date field to load
            )
        )
      )
    ) as dateUpdated
from my_table
```